# how to use missing and boolean values in the same case statement in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, select, case-statement

In VBA (MS Excel 2016): How to combine missing and boolean values in a select case statement?  The argument val could be passed as a boolean or not passed at all, or passed as something else unexpected.

```
public sub test(optional val as variant)
  select case val
    case true, isMissing(val): msgbox("foo")
    case else: msgBox("bar")
  end select
end sub
```

Above results in run-time error '13': Type mismatch on the "case true, isMissing(val):" line.

The preference is to use the same case statement allowing for multiple values to result in showing msgbox("foo").  Also would prefer not to set a default value for the optional argument on the function definition.

Each of these calls should work:

```
call test        // expect msgBox("foo")
call test("abc") // expect msgBox("bar")
call test(true)  // expect msgBox("foo")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not very elegant, another option might be:

```
Public Sub test(Optional val As Variant)
  Select Case IIf(IsMissing(val), True, val)
    Case True: MsgBox ("foo")
    Case Else: MsgBox ("bar")
  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Although not on the same case statement, this solution is better than my work around since it does not require setting a default value.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around.   VBA allows for setting a default value when an optional argument is missing.  So this worked:

```
public sub test(optional val as variant = true)
  select case val
    case true: msgbox("foo")
    case else: msgBox("bar")
  end select
end sub
```

Results as expected:

```
call test        // "foo"
call test("abc") // "bar"
call test(true)  // "foo"
```

Still would like to know if there is a way to do this on the case statement.  Maybe there isn't and this is the correct approach.

Comment: The *Variant* data-type supports null so you don't really have to assign a default value but check for null - `If IsNull(val) Then...`.